# 'Missing Dependency: /bin/sh' when installing MongoDB in AmazonAWS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I trying to follow [THIS](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/) guide to install MongoDB in AmazonAWS, but when I run this command:

```
sudo yum install -y mongo-10gen-server
```

I get this message:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-112-41-241:/bin$ sudo yum install -y mongo-10gen-server
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mongo-10gen-server.x86_64 0:2.4.10-mongodb_1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: mongo-10gen for package: mongo-10gen-server-2.4.10-mongodb_1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: mongo-10gen-server-2.4.10-mongodb_1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mongo-10gen.x86_64 0:2.4.10-mongodb_1 set to be updated
---> Package mongo-10gen-server.x86_64 0:2.4.10-mongodb_1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: mongo-10gen-server-2.4.10-mongodb_1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: mongo-10gen-server-2.4.10-mongodb_1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
mongo-10gen-server-2.4.10-mongodb_1.x86_64 from MongoDB has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: /bin/sh is needed by package mongo-10gen-server-2.4.10-mongodb_1.x86_64 (MongoDB)
Error: Missing Dependency: /bin/sh is needed by package mongo-10gen-server-2.4.10-mongodb_1.x86_64 (MongoDB)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is it Ubuntu ? or RedHat?  `yum` is the wrong package installer for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Follow these simple steps outlined in the [MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```